# JSF 2 - hiding default values on <? extends Number>

Tags: java, jsf-2, default-value

is there a way to hide the default values of my number properties? I've got a `int` field and on my view the `<h:inputText />` field shows a 0. In addition to this, if I leave this input empty I get a `NullPointerException` on this.

Can I hide the default value and treat empty inputs as default value?

I'm using `mojarra 2.1.2` on `Tomcat 7`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The primitive `int` always defaults to `0`. You want to use `Integer` instead. E.g.:

```
public class Entity {

    private Integer value;

    // ...
}
```

As to keeping it `null` while submitting empty data, add the following context param to your `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In addition, if you're using Tomcat or a clone which utilizes Apache EL parser, add the following server startup VM argument as well to prevent it from treating `Number` values like primitives:

```
-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false
```

In Eclipse, you could set it in server configuration (doubleclick the server entry in *Servers* view) in the *Arguments* tab of the *Open launch configuration* dialogue. In production, you could add it to the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable.

Comment: Cheers BalusC - on JSF topics mankind can put trust in you :)

Comment: @BalusC I am using JBoss and my Intenger values still appearing as 0 when null