# Empty value when 0 in primefaces inputtext component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this primefaces inputText component that links to a double value in my backing bean:

```
<p:inputText id="valueI"
    value="#{productMB.total}">
    <f:convertNumber type="number" maxFractionDigits="0" />
</p:inputText>
```

When the total is 0 the inputText shows a zero. I need to show an empty value because a zero is visually ugly

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Double` instead of `double` so that it defaults to `null` instead of `0.0`. Primitives can't be represented as `null` (and therefore also not render as empty).

Comment: Do you know why this doesn't work on Integer values?

Comment: It should also work for integers. Or are you observing this only after submitting a form? If so, then head to this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206401/jsf-2-hiding-default-values-on-extends-number/7206474#7206474

Comment: Yes, you are right is only after submitting the form