# Allow one empty field to be null without setting COERCE_TO_ZERO application wide

Tags: jsf, numbers, tomcat7, el, coercion

In my web app using Tomcat7 I have the following input:

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.minimum}">
    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" maxFractionDigits="4" />
</h:inputText>
```

And the respective bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {   
    private Float minimum; 
    // +getter+setter
}
```

How can I allow the user to set `null` values? When the user leaves it blank, `minimum` receives `0.0` anyway.

I have already seen [this COERCE_TO_ZERO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206401/jsf-2-hiding-default-values-on-extends-number/7206474#7206474), but then my entire application will be impacted, and I wouldn't like that, since it had been implemented considering that I would always receive 0 or empty strings from the form fields.

So I'd like to change the behavior for only one input. How could I do that? If I could keep the `converterNumber` it would be good.

Comment: If you don't mind having `null` when user explicitly types `0` then you can modify your setter to check for `0` and replace it with `null`.

Comment: @Geinmachi thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately I do need to allow the user to set 0 if he wants

Comment: You could implement your own converter, or let it store in a String backing bean attribute and then process/convert it inside the action method.